# How to develop bitcoin sidechains/second layer solutions?

Tags: client, development, sidechains

If I have an idea for a use case that requires transparency and ultra-secure final settlement, how do I go about programming this to be a side chain/2nd layer solution on the bitcoin network? Is there a specific language I'll write in? A specific client? A specific IDE? Where can I get started?

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there a specific language I'll write in?**

No.

> **A specific client?**

No.

> **A specific IDE?**

No.

> **Where can I get started?**

If you don't wish to create intellectual property rights over your ideas or software, you could start by studying the licences to existing solutions and then study their documentation and source code. If you don't want to be bound by their licences and want to develop your own intellectual property you'd need to be much more careful and might need to start with a clean-room development process meticulously avoiding any knowledge whatsoever of existing solutions.